# SideMenu Fails on Simulator and Apps

Tags: codenameone

I use the SideCommand menu, without problems, but in the last version of codenameone does not work if we use the:

```
Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(false);
```

I tried with this sample code:

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tutorial-create-a-gorgeous-sidemenu.html

Can you fix it please?

Regards

Comment: Please file an issue if this is a regression.

Comment: Posted the Issue:https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3086